# Session object in server side routing method - Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have this error when running my app and attempting to route to root/about

```
ReferenceError: Session is not defined at [object Object].route.onBeforeAction (app/lib/routes.js:38:8) at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1) at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1) at packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:121:1 at [object Object].urlencodedParser (/home/action/.parts/packages/meteor/1.0/packages/iron_router/.1.0.7.42k4wv++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:72:36) at packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:277:1 at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1) at [object Object].hookWithOptions (packages/iron:router/lib/router.js:276:1) at boundNext (packages/iron:middleware-stack/lib/middleware_stack.js:251:1) at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

Here is my routing code in this location lib/routes.js:

```
Router.map(function () {
     this.route('aboutTemplate', {
        name: 'aboutTemplate',
        where: 'server',
        path: '/about',
         onBeforeAction: function(){
           Session.set('active_menu_option','about');
           this.next();
         },
         onAfterAction: function(){

        },
        data: function(){
          return {active_menu_option: {'about':'active'}};
        }
      });
}
```

I presume the error occurs because this is now a server side route and the session object is not available outside of client scope. But is there any more information someone could give me on this?

also, while I am at it - what is the first argument representing in the above method? How is the first argument 'aboutTemplate' different from the name parameter - name: 'aboutTemplate'?

any help appreciated

Comment: [meteor-server-session](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-server-session/) might be good to know about.

Comment: huh, I looked at the brief documentation - what exactly is a serverside session vs a client side session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session is a client-only package, you will need a custom package (as told in the question comments) to get it on the server.

As for the first argument of Iron Router `route` function, it is used to specify parameters (`/posts/:id` for example) and is used by Iron Router to guess a couple parameters, such as the template to use (`Router.route('homepage')` on the client will search for the `homepage` template).

In that case, Iron Router will too guess the name, so your code is slightly redundant (but cleaner, in my own opinion). [See more in the guide.](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes)